# vue component ,how to update store state (vuex) via an async request(axios) in vue component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm working on a project using vue vuex and webpack.  I've got a Vue instance and imported a vue component and a vuex store. component and store are all registered to Vue instance. I was using axios made a async post request in the component.. After I got the result but I couldn't manipulate the store and i can't get the Vue instance or component... how could i do with it? plz?

```
app.js

import indexPage from './vue/index.vue'
const store = new Vuex.Store(....not relavent.....)
const router = new VueRouter({routes:[{path:'/', component:indexPage}]})
const app = new Vue({
    el:"#app",
    router,
    store
})


index.vue

<template>not relavent</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data(){return{}},

        methods:{ 
            dopost: function(){
                axios.post('/api',{}).then(){
                // apparently "this" wouldn't workhere
                // I've tried give this module a name and just use it
                // but it is just an object, not a instance. 
                // And I couldn't use the vue instance 
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Is there any way that i don't need to change the async request to the sync request?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the methods of your component should go in it's methods property.

```
<script>
    export default {
     data(){
      return {}
     },

     methods: {
      postTo() {
        const self = this; // assigning this to self
        axios.post('/api',{}).then(){
         self.$store.commit('SOME_MUTATION_TYPE')
        }
      }

     }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: sorry  thats a typo error     that is in the  methods……

Comment: question is that i couldnt call the mutate function after i get the response ...   "this" now becomes "window"